# Using ServiceStack, is it possible to create Derived Request class?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, servicestack

I have a situation where the only API offered to me returns many items and I want to make a derived request that will only return one item.  Here's what my attempt looks like:

```
[Route("/v3/quotes/{stockTicker}")]
[DataContract]
public class Quotes_Request : BaseRequest<Quotes_Response, List<Quote>>
{
    [DataMember(Name = "stockTicker")]
    public string Symbol { get; init; }
    
    //Properties

    [DataMember(Name = "order")]
    public virtual SortOrder? Order { get; init; } = SortOrder.asc;

    [DataMember(Name = "limit")]
    public virtual int? Limit { get; init; } = 50_000;

    public Quotes_Request(string symbol) => Symbol = symbol;
}

public class Quote_Request : Quotes_Request
{
    [DataMember(Name = "order")]
    public override SortOrder? Order => SortOrder.desc;

    [DataMember(Name = "limit")]
    public override int? Limit => 1;

    public Quote_Request(string symbol, DateTime dateTime) : base(symbol)
    {
        TimestampLessThanOrEqual = dateTime;
    }
}
```

Returning the list of quotes using `Quotes_Request` works perfectly and
I would have thought that my goal of returning a single quote with `Quote_Request` would work too, but there seems to be a problem because I get this error:

> None of the given rest routes matches 'Quote_Request' request:
> /v3/quotes/{stockTicker}:   Variable 'stockTicker' does not match any property.

To address the error, if I change the route on the parent class `Quotes_Request` to this:

```
[Route("/v3/quotes/{Symbol}")]
[DataContract]
public class Quotes_Request : BaseRequest<Quotes_Response, List<Quote>>
{
    [DataMember(Name = "stockTicker")]
    public string Symbol { get; init; }
    
    //truncated
```

The code runs but it's not correct because it's not using any of the `DataMember` attributes to name the query parameters, its using the property names. Which is actually the same thing it did with the `Route`.  Unfortunately, I can't use the property names even if I wanted to because some of the `DataMember`s actually have a period in the name.

I did try one other thing, that was I tried making the `Symbol` property `virtual` so that I could override it in the Derived `Quote_Request` class like this:

```
public class Quote_Request : Quotes_Request
{
    [DataMember(Name = "stockTicker")]
    public override string Symbol { get; init; }

    //truncated
```

But that didn't work either.  I got the same error as in the first place:

> None of the given rest routes matches 'Quote_Request' request:
> /v3/quotes/{stockTicker}:   Variable 'stockTicker' does not match any property.

I'm kinda surprised that it didn't pick up the `DataMember` name even when it was overriden but if that would have worked I would have just overriden all the properties.

Is there anything else I can try? Did I miss something?  Or is this something that will need to be fixed in ServiceStack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Request DTOs must be unique and can only implement a single API.

To share code amongst Request DTOs you can have them implement the same abstract base class.

However we'd typically recommend to avoid using inheritance in Request DTOs since they represent declarative definition of your Service Contract and using inheritance [hides their intent](https://docs.servicestack.net/why-remote-services-use-dtos#dry-vs-intent).

Comment: I think this case makes a good argument why it could be useful to allow request DTOs to be derived.  I'm not changing the inherited `Route` or `IReturn`.  I only want the ability to create requests where certain properties can't be changed.  Really the workaround isn't that bad I'll just need to create a methods that clones the derived request to the parent request type and then use that before I send it.  It's not horrible, just a lot of mappings I could avoid if ServiceStack was able to read the `DataMember` of properties that were inherited.  (lmk if you reconsider)

Comment: No there's never a good reason for Request DTOs to be inherited, they're declarative models for the explicit purpose for designing the input Service Contract for a single API. I'd recommend against inheritance since it hides its declarative Service Contract, but especially Request DTOs which define features for its unique endpoint. You can clone/map Request DTO properties in a single line with [Auto Mapping Utils](https://docs.servicestack.net/auto-mapping)

Comment: I've tested it an making a derived request DTO works perfectly fine as long as you don't need to change the name with the `DataMember(Name = "xxx")`.  How would you approach my problem of wanting to lock down certain request parameters publicly while allowing them to be set to internally?  The best way I've found to do it is to make a derived request DTO with a method that clones it back to the parent DTO type.  It's not a ton of code with mapping tools but it seems kinda redundant, doesn't it?

Comment: @LorneCash I wouldn't be trying to lockdown a Request DTO, the purpose of which is to define an APIs public Services contract. Map it do a different type and do whatever you want to do on a separate model. DTOs should be inert data models, they shouldn't contain any implementation logic.